# How to return a user input value to another class? c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and object orientated programming so please excuse me if it's a nooby question but i'm not too familiar with everything yet.
I want to ask the user for input in a method in the first class, and then return this value to a method in the second class, to work out the final cost. I understand how to pass a set value via constructors but thats as far as i know, this would be fine however i need an input value to be passed not a set value. (this code is just a bit from my main program)

```
class TableOrder
{      
    string inputtablenumber;
    int tablenumber;

    public int TableNumber()
    {
        Console.Write("please enter the table number:");
        inputtablenumber = Console.ReadLine();
        tablenumber = int.Parse(inputtablenumber);
        return tablenumber;            
    }   
}

class TableBill
{

public void CalculateBill()
    {
        TableOrder TO = new TableOrder();
        TO.AddDrink();            

        if (tablenumber >= 6 & tablenumber < 10)
        {
            Console.Write("You are due a 10% discount");

        }
        if (tablenumber > 10)
        {
            Console.Write("you are due a 15% discount");
        }

    }        
}

 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TableBill TB = new TableBill();
        TB.CalculateBill();

    }
}
```

so i want to use the number that comes from the TableNumber method in my CalculateBill class, instead of passing over an already set value. I tried with the TO.AddDrink(); but i didn't get anywhere. This is only a small snippet of my overall code so whats happening may not make too much sence but i just want to access this tablenumber value in another class. 
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you calling the `TableNumber` method? That's what you made it for, right?

Answer (score 0):

Change `int tablenumber;` to `public int tablenumber;`, then in `CalculateBill` call `TO.TableNumber` and replace `tablenumber` with `TO.tablenumber`.

Alternatively:

```
public void CalculateBill()
    {
        TableOrder TO = new TableOrder();
        var tablenumber = TO.TableNumber();
        TO.AddDrink();            

        if (tablenumber >= 6 & tablenumber < 10)
        {
            Console.Write("You are due a 10% discount");

        }
        if (tablenumber > 10)
        {
            Console.Write("you are due a 15% discount");
        }

    }        
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to make `int tablenumber` public?

Comment: `public int tablenumber;`

Comment: That is not a valid response to my question. I want to know *why* you want to do that (or think it is necessary)

Comment: Sorry, I read it as `how`. Well, it's just two different approaches. He could remove the method and put the user input in the constructor itself, then the public property will make a little more sense.

Comment: Then you should edit your answer accordingly (especially to indicate that they are two different approaches, and OP should do either one *or* the other. In the current form it sounds as though both are part of a single solution). Also you shouldn't use `Console.ReadLine();` in a constructor, it can cause strange behavior (especially on invalid input)

Comment: Thanks for the pro hint. It's already indicated with 'Alternatively' in my answer. The code by the way is so bad, it doesn't really matter if there will be Console.ReadLine in the ctor or not.